# Are there any conscious entities in the LOOP simulation or are they all just unconscious NPCS?

Tags: souls, the-ring

I have not watched the movies or read the books of The Ring/Ringu, but I found out a while ago that it actually takes place in a VR simulation. I am wondering if any of the characters in the sim are conscious or are they they all unknowing and soulless NPCs?

Comment: Are _we_ truly conscious?  Am I?  Are you?  Can either of us prove it?